# Variance of the random variable $|X \cup Y|$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random subsets of $\{1, 2, \dots, k-1, k\}$ picked uniformly at random from all $2^k$ subsets, independent of each other. What is the variance of the random variable $|X \cup Y|$?

Comment: How many ways to produce a set of finite cardinality by the union of two sets.

Comment: A good place to start is by calculating the mean (expected value) of $|X\cup Y|$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: in the union of two sets exists three possible kind of elements: elements that belongs only to $X$, elements that belongs only to $Y$, and possible elements that belongs to both sets.

Then you have to count a sum of trinomial coefficients.

And you know that for every cardinality $\ell$ exist $(k)_{\ell}$ number of different possible subsets, where $(k)_{\ell}$ is a falling factorial.

Answer (score 2):

For $i=1$ to $k$, define Bernoulli random variable $B_i$ by $B_i=1$ if $i\in X\cup Y$, and by $B_i=0$ otherwise. Then $|X\cup Y|=B_1+\dots+B_k$.

Note that $\Pr(B_i=1)=\frac{3}{4}$, and the $B_i$ are independent. Thus $|X\cup Y|$ has binomial distribution with parameters $\frac{3}{4}$ and $k$.

It follows (standard results) that our random variable has mean $\frac{3}{4}\cdot k$ and variance $\frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot k$.

Comment: How you take 3/4?

Comment: A "random" set $X$ is obtained by, for, every $i\le k$, deciding whether or not $i$ will be in $C$, with the two choices, yes and no, being equally likely.